# Indian Railway car fonts - available for the web?

Tags: font-identification

I'm in love with the fonts used on the sides of Indian Railway cars.

[image: Indian Railway font]

[image: Front on view]

[image: AC 3rd Tier lettering]

Is this just a hand-painted Gill Sans, or is this a custom font? For one thing the R's look slightly different.

Answer (score 5):

Photographing from an oblique angle doesn't make identification very easy! Everything except the C looks like Avant Garde:

[image: ITC Avant Garde]

However it might also be based on Futura:

[image: Futura]

It's almost certainly hand-painted, and the signwriter has done a good job of providing a no-nonsense sans for this application.

Comment: Good call, the terminals of the S would lead me more to Futura.

Comment: I uploaded more photos from a train I took yesterday... sorry the quality isn't too great!

Comment: Looking at the additional photos, I'm noticing small discrepancies :( The angle of the end of the "S" for example.

Comment: The R is also very different. The R is also different on the 2 pictures. Maybe they don't use some fixed font.

Comment: @KevinBurke Both the S and R in the first two images are different; the second S is Gill Sans and its R is Johnston [Underground]. All of them are hand-drawn. The third image is the work of not nearly such a competent signwriter.

Answer (score 3):

most of them resemble Johnston Sans (London Underground's font), which inspired other classics such as Gill and the closer match, Granby.

[image: johnston etc]

Answer (score 0):

Looks a lot like Granby, and that may in fact be what the original was based on. But it's definitely hand-painted. [English Grotesque](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/device/english-grotesque/) has a lot of the hand-painted-ness if you wanted a deliberately wonky font in this style, although it's a bit wider than this.